# If two iBeacons are close together, can one signal override another on the way to a device (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ibeacon, detection

I have a simple question that I can't find the answer to. I am testing an app with some iBeacons, and I observe that one of my iBeacons never begins to range...the region is monitored, its just not being detected. When I look at console output the other beacons get detected, and then a few seconds later, another beacon gets detected, but it has the same UUID/major/minor/identifier values as one of the other locations already detected.

So all but one of the beacons get recognized and their states get determined. Then it appears that one of the beacons that has already been determined, gets determined again (same info). These beacons are somewhat close together (about a meter apart in x, y but on different floors (2nd floor and 3rd floor), and I'm wondering if one beacon signal could override another...which would be why I am seeing the info for one of the beacons twice. Otherwise I'm not sure why I can't detect this one beacon.

Here is some of my code, I've combed over it and I can't find anything wrong with human error stuff like entering correct major/minor/UUID values.

This function gets called to start monitoring the beacons:

```
    func monitorBeacons() {
        print("monitorBeacons()")
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for:
            CLBeaconRegion.self) {
            print("monitorBeacons().monitoringIsAvailable")
            // Match all beacons with the specified UUID
            let proximityUUIDA = UUID(uuidString:
                "12345678-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935")
            let proximityUUIDB = UUID(uuidString:
                "E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0")

            let beaconRegionA = CLBeaconRegion(
                proximityUUID: proximityUUIDB!,
                major: 0x0001,
                minor: 0x0004,
                identifier: "locationA 49398")

            let beaconRegionB = CLBeaconRegion(
                proximityUUID: proximityUUIDB!,
                major: 0x0001,
                minor: 0x0002,
                identifier: "locationB 49267")

            let beaconRegionC = CLBeaconRegion(
                proximityUUID: proximityUUIDB!,
                major: 0x0001,
                minor: 0x0005,
                identifier: "locationC 49141")

            let beaconRegionD = CLBeaconRegion(
                proximityUUID: proximityUUIDA!,
                major: 0x0001,
                minor: 0x0002,
                identifier: "locationD DSDTECH")

            let beaconRegionE = CLBeaconRegion(
                proximityUUID: proximityUUIDB!,
                major: 0x0001,
                minor: 0x0001,
                identifier: "locationE 33803")

            self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegionA)
            self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegionB)
            self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegionC)
            self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegionD)
            self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegionE)

            print("\(String(describing: self.locationManager?.monitoredRegions)) + monitoredRegions")
        }
    }
```

This happens when their state gets determined:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
        if region is CLBeaconRegion {
            print("determined state of beacon for region - \(region)")
            // Start ranging only if the feature is available.
            if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                print("determined state of beacon and started ranging")
                locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)
                // Store the beacon so that ranging can be stopped on demand.
                beaconsToRange.append(region as! CLBeaconRegion)
            }
        }
    }
```

console output:

```
determined state of beacon for region - CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'locationA 49398', uuid:E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0, major:1, minor:4)
determined state of beacon for region - CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'locationB 49267', uuid:E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0, major:1, minor:2)
determined state of beacon for region - CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'locationC 49141', uuid:E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0, major:1, minor:5)
determined state of beacon for region - CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'locationE 33803', uuid:E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0, major:1, minor:1)
determined state of beacon for region - CLBeaconRegion (identifier:'locationE 33803', uuid:E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0, major:1, minor:1)
```

You can see the last two beacons are the same, but it shouldn't be determining the state twice for one beacon, which is why I think the signals are being confused maybe for the one I am missing `locationD DSDTECH` and `locationE 33803`.

**UPDATE**

I changed the `major/minor` values (which conflicted with another beacons...but not really because the `UUID`'s were different...so it shouldn't have mattered) and now the beacon gets recognized during `didDetermineState`...but I don't receive any info from it during ranging. I can see in the logs that it went through the `locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)` function`...so it I should be receiving info (UUID/major/minor/identifier/anything) from it.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple beacons with same UUID, major and minor will behave like as one region.

I think you missing the `status`. `didDetermineState` is called when ever state of any region changes (did exit, or did enter) or if you explicitly call `requestStateForRegion` for that region. Two states of one beacon in your logs, I think one is for status enter and other is for status exit.

In `didDetermineState` check region state and only start raging if region state is  `CLRegionStateInside`

```
if state == CLRegionStateInside {
    locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: region as! CLBeaconRegion)
    beaconsToRange.append(region as! CLBeaconRegion)
}
```

If you are already in the region `didDetermineState` won't be called unless you exit the region and enter again. To overcome this you should call `requestStateForRegion` for each region like this.

```
self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegionA)
self.locationManager?.requestState(for: beaconRegionA)
```

Comment: thanks, ill give this a shot...one thing - all of my beacons have different UUID/major/minor

Comment: print the state too, so that you would be able to see from logs enter and exit

Comment: the code didn't help...it just makes it so it only starts if you are inside the region (obviously) I am having trouble detecting it from inside the region already...and just FYI the app "Locate" detects the beacon fine...so it must be my code somewhere.

Comment: there is nothing to see with printing the state..the ibeacon never gets  to `determinedState`

Comment: I just figured it out...I think it was a bug...the beacon had the same major/minor value as another beacon with a different uuid. I changed the major/minor to something unique (even though the uuid should make it unique anyway...and it got detected.

Comment: see updated answer... for case If you are already in the region.

Comment: hey so i got it to be determined...but it isnt ranging...even though the logs say that it started ranging...no transmission to the device detected during ranging after `didDetermineState`

Answer (score 0):

So after figuring out the `didDetermineState`, I took my iBeacon and plugged it in closer to me, and it started receiving info - so it is just a crappy beacon :)